# Use CSS to control font of items in iPhone Spinner

Tags: iphone, css

Greetings,
Does anyone know if I can use CSS to change the font size of  elements when they are displayed in the iPhone spinner wheel?
The font within the spinner is enormous and my options all look like so: "Golden...AL,36034".
Thank you!

Comment: Who are you developing this app for?  If for the general public, please note that they all don't have great eyesight, hold their iPhone steady at the proper distance, have a clean unsmudged display, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No, you may not.  :)

Answer (score 1):

UIPicker has a delegate (just like a table view). So...just as you can manipulate the cells of a table view, you can change the rows of the picker through the delegate.

Here is the method you need to manipulate

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

Within this method, you can create a UIlabel, set the fonts and size, put in the text and then return the label.

You can't change a picker using CSS.